# What if I as a miner , include some wrong transactions in the block and push it . What is the process so that other nodes get notified about it?

Tags: transactions, nodes, yellow-paper

Also give tips to sail easily through the ethereum yellow paper

Comment: Blocks containing transactions that do not follow current consensus rules will be rejected. Nodes propagating invalid blocks could be dropped from the network.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking too big a question. Generally speaking, incorrect transactions are recognizable because other miners would disagree with the proofs.

Try the beigepaper. It's not as complete, but it's a starting point. https://github.com/chronaeon/beigepaper/